# mongoose onsave - stuck

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my MongoDB project I have user schema like this :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const router = express.Router();

var userSchema = new Schema({
         fName: String,
         mName: String,
         lName: String
});
var user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports.user = user;
```

I have imported it like this : `const user =require('./schema/User');`

And I'm trying to post a value like this :

```
mongoose
    .connect(URI,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
        )
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log("MongoDB connected...");


router.post('/user', function(req, res, next) {
            var u = new user({
                fName: "f",
                mName: "m",
                lName: "l",
            });
            u.save(function(error) {
                console.log("Your user has been saved!");
                if (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            })

        });


    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log("Encountered error...");
        console.log("error : "+err);
    });
```

And it is like stuck forever, neither it logs *user has been saved*, nor any error.

And finally the console show 1 connection, 0 read, 0 write, 0 byte usage.

How should I resolve this ?

Comment: add ```res.status(200).send({msg: 'save'})``` in else part of save callback function

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const app = express();

var userSchema = new Schema({
    fName: String,
    mName: String,
    lName: String
});
var user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/auth',
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
)
.then((res) => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected...");


    app.post('/user', function (req, res, next) {
        var u = new user({
            fName: "f1",
            mName: "m1",
            lName: "l1",
        });
        u.save(function (error) {
            console.log("Your user has been saved!");
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return res.status(500).send({ msg: error })
            }
            return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'save' })
        })

    });


})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("Encountered error...");
    console.log("error : " + err);
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`Server running on ${3000}`);
});
```